# Empty Lists in MVC 4 model when using Ajax.ActionLink post

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a html table that renders a list of objects. I'm calling a controller action that recieves the Model as parameter but the model's lists are all empty. I've tried every suggestion I could find but could not get it to work. I'm new to MVC 4 and I'm not sure if the problem is in the model binding or in the way that Im calling the Controller.

Obs: I'm currently using models from other project/namespace, could this be confusing the binding?

Model details:
ob has a list of lines that has a list of lines.

View Code:

```
@model SF.obDTO


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
 <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateCreation)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreation)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCreation)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreation)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCreation)
        </div>
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ListUserNotes)


     <table>
         <tr>
             <th>Conteúdo
             </th>
             <th>Completo
             </th>
         </tr>

         @InsertSubLines(Model.ListLines, 0)
     </table>
        <p>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Save", "Save", Model, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })
        </p>
 </fieldset>
}


@helper InsertSubLines(List<SF.LineDTO> pLines)
{
    if (pLines != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pLines.Count(); i++)
        {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => pLines[i].Content)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => pLines[i].Completed)
        </td>
        @InsertSubLines(pLines[i].ListLines)
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => pLines[i].ListLines)
    </tr>
        }
    }
}
```

Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(SF.obDTO pOB)
        {

            SF.Update(pOB);//Here the sublists are empty (count = 0)
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: What is this parameter you are passing in? pDepth + 1? I do not even see a second argument in InsertSubLines

Comment: have you read this link?  shows a lot about model binding to lists http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: try renaming you helper parameter name from `pLines` to `ListLines`.

Comment: @Jack as i simplified the code to leave only the main logic I forgot to remove this parameter passing. Its corrected now.

Comment: @Slicksim Yes, I tried the tips covered there. The inputs are displaying what seams to me as a correct name according to this article.

Comment: @Amila, Tried it, did not solve the problem.